# Query with Dynamic field values of Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-lite

With the below structure of Couchbase bucket, how do I query if the nested doc has dynamic field name?

Here, I would like to return the customer docs who have account in `Hyderabad`

I tried to query this way but couldn't succeed.

```
select * from bucket where accounts.$.city = 'Hyderabad'
```

I was expecting to return the customer doc with email `kp711@yahoo.com` but couldn't succeed.

Couchbase docs

```
[
{
  "type": "customer",
  "customer_id": <UUID4>,
  "user_type": "owner",
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "email": "kp711@yahoo.com",
  "password": "",
  "phone_number": 11111,
  "accounts": {
    <account_id which is UUID4>: {
      "amount": "500",
      "city": "Hyderabad"
    }
  }
},
{
    "type": "customer",
    "customer_id": <UUID4>,
    "user_type": "employee",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "email": "px800@yahoo.com",
    "password": "",
    "phone_number": 33333,
    "accounts": {
      <account_id which is UUID4>: {
        "amount": "500",
        "city": "Chennai"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way in Couchbase to fetch in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bucket AS b
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(b.accounts) SATISFIES v.city = 'Hyderabad' END;
```

OR

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bucket AS b
WHERE ANY n:v IN b.accounts SATISFIES v.city = 'Hyderabad' END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from VSR provides a neat solution to the problem.  Remember also that you will want to provide an index in order to leverage the Couchbase query services optimally.  I'm guessing (based on your doc examples) that you will have multiple document types included in your bucket. With that in mind, here is an example index create statement:

```
create index idxTypeCustomer on bucket(type) where type = 'customer';
```

Now you can use it as part of your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bucket AS b
WHERE type = 'customer'
  AND ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(b.accounts) SATISFIES v.city = 'Hyderabad' END;
```